# Add content to div with php dynamically

Tags: php, javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm making a contact form. When the form is submitted I want to add a success or error message to a Bootstrap modal.

Here is the button that submits the form and opens the modal.

```
<input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" data-toggle="modal" href="#contactModal"/>
```

So when the button is clicked it submits the form and opens the modal. Is there a way to add a string of text to the modal dynamically upon `success` or `failure` of the script?

Here is the PHP success/failure action currently

```
if ($success){
print "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=contactthanks.html">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=error.html">";
}
```

But I want it to add content to the modal instead of adding a `<meta>` tag that redirects the page

Here is the modal code

```
<div id="contactModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Thanks!</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>I'm pretty busy sometimes but I'll try my best to message you back <strong>ASAP</strong>!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

So how would I `print` to the inside of a `<div>` within the modal without refreshing the page or redirecting?

I don't know any PHP or AJAX and I'm just not starting to begin JS and jQuery (two days to be exact)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot submit a form and not have the page refresh. What you most likely want to do is use an AJAX request to your php instead, which will return the success/failure status as JSON, which you will then use to conditionally add content to your div with javascript.

Instead of a form, you will just use a normal `<input type="button" />` with an `onclick="someFunction"` where someFunction makes the AJAX call.

You will want to use jQuery.

Your php would look like

```
//do something with submitted values

if ($success){
    echo json_encode(True);
}
else{
    echo json_encode(False);
}
```

and the AJAX call would be something like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "dosomething.php",
    data: { formValue1 = <get value using jquery>, etc... }
    dataType: "json",
    success: processData,
    error: function(){ alert("failed"); }
});

function processData(data)
{
    if(data) {
        $("div#divid").html("what you want to add inside the div");
    }
}
```